# SVG Button Toggle

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, svg

I'm trying to toggle an SVG button from one state to the other.
They are two separate SVGs contained in a larger SVG.

For reference I've attached these images here:

[image]

[image]

So far I have come up with this where onclick I change the ID value from display on or off as shown below. I'm sure there is a much cleaner way to do this using jQuery?

HTML
SVG Code was to long so I've added to pastebin

https://pastebin.com/qnEDLthz

JS Code

```
$( "#off-btn-nav-01-category" ).on( "click", function() {
  $("#off-btn-nav-01-category").css("display", "none");
  $("#on-btn-nav-01-category").css("display", "block");
});

$( "#on-btn-nav-01-category" ).on( "click", function() {
  $("#on-btn-nav-01-category").css("display", "none");
  $("#off-btn-nav-01-category").css("display", "block");
});
```

Comment: Please see [ask], then revise to show more detail. It's very difficult to debug with no HTML. Your title should be a clear, specific question.

Comment: Your _simplified_ code needs to be here, not on another site. This isn't so complex a problem you can't put a demo snippet in your post.

Comment: You can probably mock the structure with simple div elements. All that really matters is their positional relationship.

Comment: Is the jQuery code you have currently shown supposed to handle _one_ single button only? You should use _one_ click handler for all the "on", and one for all the "off" buttons here. Inside the callback, you can use `$(this)` to get the reference to the clicked button, and via some DOM traversal methods you can go up to some common ancestor element, to then find the button's "counterpart" in there.

Comment: _"is there any way to have this svg file externally so I can apply css properties to it?"_ - no, not really. It has to be _directly_ in the DOM, otherwise your page's CSS won't have "access." Using `img`, `object` or anything like that to embed the SVG, encapsulates it from any manipulation from the outside.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the startswith operator for jQuery selector, mine the number and type from the id and apply it in your further selectors:

```
$('[id^="off-btn-nav"], [id^="on-btn-nav"]').click(function() {
    let idParts = this.id.split("-");
    let number = idParts[idParts.length - 2];
    if (idParts[0] === "on") {
        $(`#on-btn-nav-${number}-${idParts[idParts.length - 1]}`).hide();
        $(`#off-btn-nav-${number}-${idParts[idParts.length - 1]}`).show();
    } else {
        $(`#on-btn-nav-${number}-${idParts[idParts.length - 1]}`).show();
        $(`#off-btn-nav-${number}-${idParts[idParts.length - 1]}`).hide();
    }
});
```

Excuse me for not creating a snippet, stackoverflow.com said it would be too long.

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/tygkjLvf/

Comment: I quite like this approach only thing that is missing is a way to differentiate which button is pressed with and alert.
e.g. if " 01-category" is pressed display alert and same goes for the others e.g. 02-price or 03-time

Comment: @Mit the type can be reached via `idParts[idParts.length - 1]`.

Comment: Right, I've taken a crack at this, I'm still in early stages of learning JS
I've tried this approach which hasn't worked
`idParts[5] === "mor") `

Comment: @Mit don't worry, I was in your shoes at some point and I know how is it to be a beginner, so I quite understand the difficulties you face and I'm happy to help when/if I can.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using inline svg's like you say then you can just toggle the id referenced in the svg.

```js
$(".Icon use").on("click", function() {
  if ($(this).attr("href") === "#Icon-On") {
    $(this).attr("href", "#Icon-Off");
  } else {
    $(this).attr("href", "#Icon-On");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div style="height: 0; width: 0; position: absolute; visibility: hidden;">
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
<symbol id="Icon-On" viewBox="0 0 1024 1024">
<path class="Path1" d="M512 32l-480 480h288v512h384v-512h288z" />
</symbol>
<symbol id="Icon-Off" viewBox="0 0 1024 1024">
<path class="Path1" d="M864 128l-480 480-224-224-160 160 384 384 640-640z" />
</symbol>
</svg>
</div>

<svg class="Icon"><use href="#Icon-Off" /></svg>
<svg class="Icon"><use href="#Icon-Off" /></svg>
```